# How can I create a nested json structure including a []byte type?

Tags: json, go, ssl-certificate

I'm currently trying to create the following nested json including a list of json and DER encoded byte array () of a certificate using golang:

```
{
"webhooks":
    [{
    "clientConfig":{
         "caBundle":"<derData []bytes>"
    },
    "name":"sth_name"
    }]
}
```

Because of `<certDerBytes[]>`, I need to use a struct, but I don't know how to initialize it. 
I've created the struct so far:

```
type jsonstruct struct {
    Webhooks []struct {
        ClientConfig struct {
            CaBundle string `json:"caBundle"`
        } `json:"clientConfig"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"webhooks"`
}
```

But cannot instantiate the struct which I have to marshal into json.

I've tried using string literals, many ways of initializing it as you would for a normal non-nested struct.

I've also dividing up the structs i.e. `type jsonstruct..` `type webhooks ...`, etc, but that errored.

I've also  initialized the struct from the inside out, but didn't work either.

I need to create the

Comment: Please show the actual code you tried and the specific issues you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off probably using `base64` on the byte array itself, and include that as the payload of the struct field.

One piece of nit, I personally do not like nested named-structs. Breaking them out lets you have much more flexibility in your code.

For example:

```
type jsonstruct struct {
    Webhooks []Webhook `json:"webhooks"`
}

type Webhook struct {
    ClientConfig ClientConfig `json:"clientConfig"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type ClientConfig struct {
    CaBundle string `json:"caBundle"`
}

func (cc ClientConfig) ToBytes() []byte {
    return []byte(base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cc.CaBundle))
}

func (cc ClientConfig) FromBytes(cert []byte) {
    cc.CaBundle = base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(cert)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works. Is there a reason why you recommend encoding the byte array in `base64`?

Comment: JSON doesn't support native binary or byte data. As a result, we need to convert our byte strings to string representations of our data. If we just use `strings()` around out `byte[]` array, we may get out of bound ASCII characters that are non-compliant with JSON's spec (weird characters like `�`, etc). Base64 encoding ensures our data does not violate the expected characters within the JSON payload.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for the detailed explanation!